# Python pandas time series w/ hierarchical indexing and rolling/ shifting

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index, rolling-computation

Struggling with pandas' rolling and shifting concept. There are many good suggestions including in this forum but I failed miserably to apply these to my scenario.

Now I use traditional looping over the time series but ugh, it took like 8 hours to iterate over 150,000 rows which is about 3 days of data for all tickers. Got 2 months data to process it probably won't finish after I come back from a sabbatical, not mentioning risk of electricity cut off after which I'd have to start over again this time no sabbatical while waiting.

I have the following 15 min stock price time series (Hierarchical index on datetime(timestamp) and ticker, the only original column is closePrice):

```
                                     closePrice
    datetime               ticker
    2014-02-04 09:15:00    AAPL      xxx
                           EQIX      xxx
                           FB        xxx
                           GOOG      xxx
                           MSFT      xxx
    2014-02-04 09:30:00    AAPL      xxx
                           EQIX      xxx
                           FB        xxx
                           GOOG      xxx
                           MSFT      xxx
    2014-02-04 09:45:00    AAPL      xxx
                           EQIX      xxx
                           FB        xxx
                           GOOG      xxx
                           MSFT      xxx
```

I need to add two columns:

1. 12sma, 12 days moving average. Having searched SO for hours the best suggestion would be to use rolling_mean, so I tried. But it didn't work given my TS structure i.e. it works top down the first MA is calculated based on the first 12 rows regardless of different ticker values. How do I make it average based on the index i.e. first datetime then ticker so I get MA for say AAPL? Currently it does (AAPL+EQIX+FB+GOOG+MSFT+AAPL...up to 12th row) / 12
2. Once I got the 12sma column, I need 12ema column, 12 days exponential MA. For the calculation, the first value in the time series for each ticker would just copy 12sma value from the same row. Subsequently, I'd need closePrice from the same row and 12ema from the previous row i.e. past 15 min. I did a long research seems like the solution would be a combination of rolling and shifting but I can't figure out how to put it together.

Any help I'd be grateful.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Jeff's tips, after swapping and sorting ix level I am able to get the 12sma right with rolling_mean() and with a effort managed to insert the first 12ema value copied from 12sma at the same timestamp:

```
                                 close  12sma  12ema
    sec_code datetime
    AAPL     2014-02-05 11:45:00 113.0  NaN    NaN
             2014-02-05 12:00:00 113.2  NaN    NaN
             2014-02-05 13:15:00 112.9  NaN    NaN
             2014-02-05 13:30:00 113.2  NaN    NaN
             2014-02-05 13:45:00 113.0  NaN    NaN
             2014-02-05 14:00:00 113.1  NaN    NaN
             2014-02-05 14:15:00 113.3  NaN    NaN
             2014-02-05 14:30:00 113.3  NaN    NaN
             2014-02-05 14:45:00 113.3  NaN    NaN
             2014-02-05 15:00:00 113.2  NaN    NaN
             2014-02-05 15:15:00 113.2  NaN    NaN
             2014-02-05 15:30:00 113.3  113.16 113.16
             2014-02-05 15:45:00 113.3  113.19 NaN
             2014-02-05 16:00:00 113.2  113.19 NaN
             2014-02-06 09:45:00 112.6  113.16 NaN
             2014-02-06 10:00:00 113.5  113.19 NaN
             2014-02-06 10:15:00 113.8  113.25 NaN
             2014-02-06 10:30:00 113.5  113.29 NaN
             2014-02-06 10:45:00 113.7  113.32 NaN
             2014-02-06 11:00:00 113.5  113.34 Nan
```

I understand pandas has pandas.stats.moments.ewma but I prefer to use a formula I got from a book which needs close price 'at the moment' and 12ema from previous row.

So, I tried to fill 12ema column from Feb 5, 15:45 and onward. I tried apply() with a function but shift gave an error:

```
    def f12ema(x):
        K = 2 / (12 + 1)
        return x['price_nom'] * K + x['12ema'].shift(-1) * (1-K)

    df1.apply(f12ema, axis=1)

    AttributeError: ("'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'shift'", u'occurred at index 2014-02-05 11:45:00')
```

Another possibility that crossed my mind is rolling_appy() but it is beyond my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Create a date range inclusive of the times you want

```
In [47]: rng = date_range('20130102 09:30:00','20130105 16:00:00',freq='15T')

In [48]: rng = rng.take(rng.indexer_between_time('09:30:00','16:00:00'))

In [49]: rng
Out[49]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-01-02 09:30:00, ..., 2013-01-05 16:00:00]
Length: 108, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

Create a frame similar to yours (2000 tickers x dates)

```
In [50]: df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(rng)*2000,1),columns=['close'],index=MultiIndex.from_product([rng,range(2000)],names=['date','ticker']))
```

Reorder the levels so that its ticker x date for the index, SORT IT!!!!

```
In [51]: df = df.swaplevel('ticker','date').sortlevel()

In [52]: df
Out[52]: 
                               close
ticker date                         
0      2013-01-02 09:30:00  0.840767
       2013-01-02 09:45:00  1.808101
       2013-01-02 10:00:00 -0.718354
       2013-01-02 10:15:00 -0.484502
       2013-01-02 10:30:00  0.563363
       2013-01-02 10:45:00  0.553920
       2013-01-02 11:00:00  1.266992
       2013-01-02 11:15:00 -0.641117
       2013-01-02 11:30:00 -0.574673
       2013-01-02 11:45:00  0.861825
       2013-01-02 12:00:00 -1.562111
       2013-01-02 12:15:00 -0.072966
       2013-01-02 12:30:00  0.673079
       2013-01-02 12:45:00  0.766105
       2013-01-02 13:00:00  0.086202
       2013-01-02 13:15:00  0.949205
       2013-01-02 13:30:00 -0.381194
       2013-01-02 13:45:00  0.316813
       2013-01-02 14:00:00 -0.620176
       2013-01-02 14:15:00 -0.193126
       2013-01-02 14:30:00 -1.552111
       2013-01-02 14:45:00  1.724429
       2013-01-02 15:00:00 -0.092393
       2013-01-02 15:15:00  0.197763
       2013-01-02 15:30:00  0.064541
       2013-01-02 15:45:00 -1.574853
       2013-01-02 16:00:00 -1.023979
       2013-01-03 09:30:00 -0.079349
       2013-01-03 09:45:00 -0.749285
       2013-01-03 10:00:00  0.652721
       2013-01-03 10:15:00 -0.818152
       2013-01-03 10:30:00  0.674068
       2013-01-03 10:45:00  2.302714
       2013-01-03 11:00:00  0.614686

                                 ...

[216000 rows x 1 columns]
```

Groupby the ticker. Return a DataFrame for each ticker that is the application of rolling_mean and ewma. Note that are many options for controlling this, e.g windowing, you could make it not wrap around days, etc.

```
In [53]: df.groupby(level='ticker')['close'].apply(lambda x: concat({ 'spma' : pd.rolling_mean(x,3), 'ema' : pd.ewma(x,3) }, axis=1))
Out[53]: 
                                 ema      spma
ticker date                                   
0      2013-01-02 09:30:00  0.840767       NaN
       2013-01-02 09:45:00  1.393529       NaN
       2013-01-02 10:00:00  0.480282  0.643504
       2013-01-02 10:15:00  0.127447  0.201748
       2013-01-02 10:30:00  0.270334 -0.213164
       2013-01-02 10:45:00  0.356580  0.210927
       2013-01-02 11:00:00  0.619245  0.794758
       2013-01-02 11:15:00  0.269100  0.393265
       2013-01-02 11:30:00  0.041032  0.017067
       2013-01-02 11:45:00  0.258476 -0.117988
       2013-01-02 12:00:00 -0.216742 -0.424986
       2013-01-02 12:15:00 -0.179622 -0.257750
       2013-01-02 12:30:00  0.038741 -0.320666
       2013-01-02 12:45:00  0.223881  0.455406
       2013-01-02 13:00:00  0.188995  0.508462
       2013-01-02 13:15:00  0.380972  0.600504
       2013-01-02 13:30:00  0.188987  0.218071
       2013-01-02 13:45:00  0.221125  0.294942
       2013-01-02 14:00:00  0.009907 -0.228185
       2013-01-02 14:15:00 -0.041013 -0.165496
       2013-01-02 14:30:00 -0.419688 -0.788471
       2013-01-02 14:45:00  0.117299 -0.006936

       2013-01-04 10:00:00 -0.060415  0.341013
       2013-01-04 10:15:00  0.074068  0.604611
       2013-01-04 10:30:00 -0.108502  0.440256
       2013-01-04 10:45:00 -0.514229 -0.636702
                                 ...       ...

[216000 rows x 2 columns]
```

Pretty good perf as its essentially looping over the tickers.

```
In [54]: %timeit df.groupby(level='ticker')['close'].apply(lambda x: concat({ 'spma' : pd.rolling_mean(x,3), 'ema' : pd.ewma(x,3) }, axis=1))
1 loops, best of 3: 2.1 s per loop
```

Comment: Many thanks Jeff! Took me a while to study your answer. I didn't know what swapping index level can achieve until I read your answer and sorting the index definitely speed up things!